# rsync files that are in remote directory's subfolder

Tags: rsync

I have an old copy of the remote folder (FD) `user@IP:/folder1/folder2/folder3/FD/` which has subfolders fol1, fol2, ...,

```
user@IP:/folder1/folder2/folder3/FD/
                                   |__fol1
                                   |__fol2
                                   |__ ...
```

that contain many files.
My local folder has the same name and the same subfolders

```
/localfd1/localfd2/FD/
                     |__fol1
                     |__fol2
                     |__ ...
```

How can I copy from the remote subfolders only the newer files at my local subfolders? scp would copy the entire folders but i only want the new files.

More analyticaly:
The OLD COPY of the remote folder that I have, has the structure:

```
/localfd1/localfd2/FD/
                     |__fol1
                          |_old file1
                          |_old file2
                          |_old file3 
                     |__fol2
                          |_old file4
                          |_old file5
```

the NEW_REMOTE folder NOW has the form:

```
 user@IP:/folder1/folder2/folder3/FD/
                                    |__fol1
                                         |_old file3 
                                         |_new file_a
                                         |_new file_b  
                                    |__fol2
                                         |_old file5 
                                         |_new file_c
```

(some files in the remote folder was deleted in order to save space + new files are added).

I want to copy from the NEW_REMOTE folders (fol1 and fol2) only the NEW files at my local folder. So my new local folder will have the form:

```
/localfd1/localfd2/FD/
                     |__fol1
                          |_old file1
                          |_old file2
                          |_old file3 
                          |_new file_a
                          |_new file_b 
                     |__fol2
                          |_old file4
                          |_old file5
                          |_new file_c
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this phrase, "How can I copy from the remote subfolders only the newer files at my local subfolders" - can you give examples, i.e. files in both locations, which are newer or older and which ones you want to copy and in which direction.

Comment: @EightBitTon I edited my question for you adding the section "More analyticaly: ..." thnx for yr time and interest

Comment: @phaethon100 : my answer was not helpful to your question ?

Comment: @ arzyfex , it worked like a charm! thank you. U need to be careful though adding "/" at  the end of the folders

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
rsync -avh --update user@IP:/folder1/folder2/folder3/FD/ /localfd1/localfd2/FD/
```

from `man rsync` :

> This  forces  rsync  to  skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source
>                 file.  (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the source file’s, it will be updated if  the  sizes
>                 are different.)